# How can I create EF by APDU commands on Gemalto IdPrime 930 smartcard

Tags: smartcard, apdu, gemalto

I'm trying to create EF on the smartcard using APDU command:
`80 E0 00 00 1C 62 1A 80 01 80 82 01 01 83 02 55 5A 86 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 A5 03 83 01 00`
and get the error **69 85** (Condition of use not satisfied:- more than 1 logical channel open - selected logical channel not channel 0).

I'm sending this APDU just after ATR.
What's wrong? It's a new card, do I need verify PIN before the file creating operation?

Update:
I added PIN verification and SELECT MF:
<Send: 00 21 00 11 06 31 32 33 34 35 36
Rcv: 90 00
Send: 00 A4 00 0C 3F 00
Rcv: 90 00>
But still get 6985 after CREATE command mentioned above (

Comment: First of all: access to CREATE FILE command is restricted by access control. So, you need to verify PIN or to pass authentication or to do something else.  SW=6985 usually means that you should send some commands before CREATE FILE. Details depend on chip OS.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I did PIN-verification and select MF with status code 9000, but I still get 69 85 error (

Answer (score 0):

No experience with Gemalto-cards, but 69 85 typically indicates, that the command may be correct in principle, but has some preconditions currently not fulfilled, like the attempt to perform a challenge-response test without previously retrieving a random number, use of a key which not got a valid value etc. Are you sure, that the card is in a state, where new files may be created?

If an access right acquired by VERIFY would be missing, there is no real alternative to 69 82 "Security status not satisfied".